# Can you explain how lines 8 and 9 of the code worked?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I do not understand how lines 8 and 9 in below code works. If someone were to describe this two lines, the code would be easy for me to understand.

Below is the code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
form_page = session.get('http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd')
form = BeautifulSoup(form_page.content, 'lxml')

#Line 8:
captcha = eval(form.form.table.table.find_all('tr')[6].find_all('td')[1].get_text())
#Line 9:
data = dict(sr=3,et=0,exam='ssc', year='2011', board="comilla", roll="16072541", reg="8718001254", value_s=captcha)
```

Comment: That line read the code inside that url as a string. Then use eval to execute that code. Then create a Python dict with keyword=value as params

Comment: please exaplain eval function how to work, I don't understand. please explain in details @ToanQuocHo

Comment: eval("string") will execute "string" as if it was a part of your code.

Comment: @HumayunAhmadRajib python is [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Comment: Also and FWIW, this code is a **MAJOR** [security breach](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). Anyone running this code on one of our servers (or even desktops) would be fired immediatly, and possibly even sued.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A html table is built like this:

A bunch of rows `<tr>`, and each row has some columns `<td>`.

What the captcha line does is:

1. `find_all('tr')`: get all rows (`<tr>`)
2. `[6]`: get the 7th row specifically
3. `find_all('td')` inside that row, get all the columns (`<td>`)
4. `[1]`: get the second column specifically

We now have a table cell with a single value in it.

5) `get_text()` Get the actual text content of that cell.

You can read the dots "x.y" as "return y from x"

Now, `eval()` will execute this table cell value as if it was a part of the code. Whatever value that execution returns is stored in the `captcha` variable.

`eval("print('hello')")` is the same as `print('hello')`

The data line just builds a dictionary. I'm not sure I understand the names used, but you can call members by name with a dictionary, like `data['sr']` which will then return 3.
`data['value_s']` stores the value of `captcha`

Answer (score 1):

How line 8 works is that it allows the owner of the resource you are reading (at http://www.educationboardresults.gov.bd) to execute arbitrary code on your machine.

For example, if the owner was to put in the table `__import__(“shutil”).rmtree(“/“, True)` then they’ve just managed to toast every file you have permission to.

So, you may wish to consider rewriting line 8 entirely.